# How to create a new list everytime you loop and repeat the loop after appending elements to it?

Tags: python

This is my list

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,9,10,1]
```

I want this output

```
[1][2,3][4,4,5][6,7][8,8,9][9][10,1]
```

If the number is even and the next number is odd loop should `break`, and the next odd or even number should be appended in another list.
if there is even number, the list shouldn't be broken until the next odd is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lis = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,9,10,1] 
tempList = []
result = []
for item in lis:
    tempList.append(item)
    if item % 2 == 1:
        result.append(tempList)
        tempList = []
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me the output I want [[1], [2, 3], [4, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 8, 9], [9], [10, 1]]

Comment: Is there a way to get the same output in dictionary instead of a list , like this : [{1},{2:3},{4,4:5}{6:7}.....]

Comment: is this a homework? you should atleast give an approach on how you think this should be done and not expect people to solve your problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to formulate a solution using `break` here.

May I suggest that you rewrite your psuedo-algorithm a little more concisely first. Something like:

1. For every item in the input list, append it to an output list.
2. If the item is odd then remember the current output list, and start
   a new one.

Then, implemented in Python it looks like:

```
input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 1]
output_list = [[]]

for x in input_list:
    output_list[-1].append(x)
    if x % 2 != 0:
        output_list.append([])
```